# ng-table: check box selection in each row

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a ng-table where i am trying to implement selection using check box in each row.

```
 <table id="List" class=" table table-bordered table-striped"
  ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" template-pagination="custom/pager"> 

 <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in $data" >
          <td style="width: 35px">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedIds[]"  value="{{item.id}}" ng-checked="isRowSelected(item.id)" ng-click="toggleSelection(item.id)" />
        </td>
 <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'Name'"  filter="{ 'Name': 'text' }" >
        {{ item.Name}} </a>   

    </td>
     <td data-title="'Email'" sortable="'Email'" >
        {{ item.Email}}
  </td>
  <td data-title="'Phone Number'" sortable="'PhoneNumber'"> 
      {{ item.PhoneNumber}}
            </td>
    </tr>
```

this is the controller:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("ListController",
 function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$scope.selectedIds = [];
    $scope.toggleSelection = function (val) {
             var idx = $scope.selectedIds.indexOf(val);
             if (idx > -1) {
                 $scope.selectedIds.splice(idx, 1);
             } else {
                 $scope.selectedIds.push(val);
             }
         };

         $scope.isRowSelected = function (id) {
             return $scope.selectedIds.indexOf(id) >= 0;
         };
         $scope.isAnythingSelected = function () {
             return $scope.selectedIds.length > 0;
         };
});
```

i am trying to select individual rows however the above code selecting all the rows on any row click.
any suggestion on this please?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle as example ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the power of angular correctly :)
You should try something like that in your view:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.isRowSelected" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)" />
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function(item){
    item.isRowSelected = !item.isRowSelected;
}


$scope.isAnythingSelected = function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++){
        if($scope.data[i].isRowSelected === true){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```